# Spring Async method calls another service's async method, but that never gets executed?

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous

I have a Spring-Boot application, which has (for this case) a controller and a couple of services. The controller handler method is synchronous, but it calls an `@Async` annotated method on a service that forks a number of secondary tasks the controller has not to wait for. Debug information shows that the method is called in a separate thread, so in general my application setup for `@Async` handling is functional (taskExecutor bean, `@EnableAsync` and so on). But something is still not right - the service has to call another service to fork out more IO tasks and that service method is also marked `@Async`. I cannot see this secondary async calls being executed during testing, but I see them being stepped in the first service. Neither log messages nor breakpoints are hit. Are there rules in Spring framework about `@Async` methods calling `@Async` methods on other beans that I have missed?

Comment: I have worked on that kind of application, it would not have functioned at all if there was any limitation like that. It doesnt seem plausible there would be a rule like that. But maybe the application could run out of pooled threads and hang?

Comment: I am still debugging this. Right now I have proven during a unit test that calling the Async method triggers twice a `submitCompletable` on `AsyncTaskExecutor`, and debugging deeper shows both tasks ending up in the `workQueue` of the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.  I just cannot see what stops that one from consuming the queue yet.

Comment: Using a test won't work due to the async nature. As soon as you call the controller method and that is finished your test ends and as such also the async call chain.

Comment: Not true. I have my mockMVC test returning and at a breakpoint where I check another web call to await completion. I definitely can see threads still do their thing after the initial synchronous call returned.